# Flutter application signing key failed

Tags: android, flutter

I have made a Flutter application and launched it on the play store. [This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.souparnika.newsapp)

I used a key to sign while uploading it. But then I lost it and had to create a new key for it. But now the Playstore is not accepting the new key. How to go about it. Do I have to make a new application? I am not able to add a release at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You have replace the signing key on Play console
Under `Release Management` there is a section for `App signing`
In this section you find option for `Request Key Upgrade`

Comment: Yeah had to do that only. But I was hoping if there is some other way.